# Import/export Gmail contacts?

Tags: gmail, google-contacts, migrate-data

I have two Gmails. One is for school, and is part of the organization. The other is personal. I've already set up forwarding from school to personal and set it so that I can send email from my school account while logged in to my personal account. The school one automatically has the school emails of every student and teacher loaded on, which makes it a real pain when I try to send from my school email within my personal email. How can I export contacts from my school email and import them to my personal email?

Comment: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/24911?hl=en ?

Answer (score 1):

As Franck [pointed out](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/57524/import-export-gmail-contacts#comment45739_57524) Google has documentation on how to export [here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/24911) and how to import [here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14024). These are the steps:

Open the Gmail account from which you want to export contacts and go to the contacts section
[image: Go to contacts]

Open the `More` menu and click `Export...`
[image: Open export menu]

In the Export dialog that should appear, make sure `All contacts` and `Google CSV format` are selected (if you want to import all your contacts into your other account). Press export and save the file somewhere where you can easily find it.
[image: How to export]

Then log in to the account where you want to import the contacts.

Again, go to the Contacts section and open the `More` menu. This time, choose `Import...`
[image: Go to import]

In the dialog box that appears, open the file you exported and press import.
[image: How to import]

The imported contacts will be added to a group called `Imported [Today's date]`
[image: Imported group]